# Magento 1.9 custom module observer is not getting called

Tags: magento-1.9, module, event-observer, magento-1

This is my config code of custom module :

```
<controller_action_predispatch_cms_index_index>
          <observers>
              <mage_homepage_model_observer>
                  <model>mage_homepage/observer</model>
                  <method>homepage</method>
              </mage_homepage_model_observer>
          </observers>
  </controller_action_predispatch_cms_index_index>
```

& this is my observer in model folder :

```
<?php
class Mage_Homepage_Model_Observer
{

  public function homepage()
  {//mycode
  }
}
```

but it does not come in this function. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the same `config.xml` file as [your other question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/147977/2380), you need to replace:

```
<model>mage_homepage/observer</model>
```

With:

```
<model>homepage/observer</model>
```